# Spring security OAuth2 token introspection

Tags: spring, security, oauth, token, introspection

i try to use Spring security to valid OAuth2 token by introspection.
Actually my application dont try to hit OAuth server for introspection et return 403 when i call my controller.

My conf:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri=https://example.net/introspection
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id=clientId
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret=clientSecret
```

Websecurity:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping(value = "/foo", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void uploadMedia(BearerTokenAuthentication bearerTokenAuthentication,
                        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String bearerToken){

        System.out.println(bearerTokenAuthentication.getToken().getTokenValue());
    }
}
```

How to use spring securty to valid OAuth token by introspection ?

Mathieu

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, did you found the solution?

Comment: I've configured my resource server as it is in the question and it works for me. (using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server dependency version 3.1.2).  Please set the logs to debug or trace to investigate why the problem occurs for you. Also it could help to copy the token and call your introspection-uri using Postman to verify if you actually use the server properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And in application property, you can specify

```
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token.
```

Now , core class - RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication will be used to call authorization server.
You can put it in debug.

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=client1
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret1
```

Comment: Just note about `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`: "This project is a port of the Spring Security OAuth support that came with Spring Boot 1.x. Support was removed in favor of Spring Security 5’s first class OAuth support."

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/

So future reader probably should try to go with `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri` instead.